# Can we remove unit productions First Before removing Null productions?

Tags: terminology, context-free, formal-grammars, normal-forms

My professor have asked me strange question , about converting from Context free grammar to chomsky normal form , Can we remove unit productions first from CFG if possible , before removing null productions , does it effect the Chomsky normal form ?

Comment: What do you think? Have you tried it?

Comment: yes , i have but gives new CNF

Comment: So then it sounds like you've answered your own question?  If you have an example where removing null productions yields a different Chomsky normal form than when not removing null productions, you have an answer.  Would you like to write up an answer that answers your own question, with a detailed example and explanation?

Comment: Why would it be a problem if you get another CNF grammar? I don't think anyone claims that the CNF of a CFG is unique.

Comment: @Raphael There is often a confusion between normal form and canonical form. It is often the case that normal form is not unique while canonical form is unique ... but this distinction is not always respected. See [wikipedia on canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form). So the confusion of the question poster is understandable.  My opinion is that **this is a good question** as it clarifies a point that is often overlooked, even if it is a very simple one. However, it might be more useful with another title: *Is Chomsky Normal Form unique?*, for example.

Comment: @babou In my experience, textbooks will present a couple of theorems of the form "Every CFG with X can be transformed into an equivalent one with X plus Y" that lead from an unrestriced CFG via reduced and then chain-rule-free grammars to CNF. The observant reader will be able to decide if the theorems resp. the constructions from the proofs can be applied in any sequence. Hence my comment and downvote: the OP should have enough material at hand to investigate on their own, and the question in its current form suggests that they did not bother to.

Comment: @Raphael Textbooks say about everything that is being asked here, or at least a sizable oart of it. I gave my feeling on the issue, but I will not fight for it. Abstracting from available material is something that you or I do routinely. I am not sure it is so obvious and natural for many people.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in removing the unit productions first except when in the  next step while removing the null productions the grammar might be transformed into one which again has unit productions and you have to repeat the steps again to reach a cnf.